# How to know whether Apache is install or not from centos 7

Tags: linux, apache, centos

I am new to centos 7. I want to  install apache (httpd). so i command yum install httpd it says already installed. but i could find any file in etc directory.
There is folder in etc httpd but no file are there in this directory.

Comment: find / -name httpd

Answer (score 4):

In CentOS there are no files in `/etc/httpd` since they are all in subdirectories.

`/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` is main configuration file, and there are additional configuration files in `/etc/httpd/conf.d` and `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d` directories which are included by main file.

To see in browser that Apache is installed, first start Apache using following command and then open `http://localhost` in browser:

```
sudo systemctl start httpd
```

You can also ask Apache status from commandline with command:

```
sudo systemctl status httpd
```

I'm not completely sure about what that outputs in all cases, but seems to output at least `Loaded: loaded` on second line when Apache has been installed.

Comment: Yes you are correct. but how to test in browser apache is installed are not. is there any way to test it

Comment: @jvk I added answer to 'in browser' question

Answer (score 0):

The unix **which** command shows the full path of a command.

In order to check if Apache is installed, just check from the console if any of possible apache command exists :

```
> which apache || which httpd || which apache2
```

If there is no answer, Apache is not available...